# Python-Requests receive client private key as string

Tags: python, http, ssl, https, python-requests

### My Question

I'm trying to use an encrypted client private key when using [python requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/). As it doesn't support encrypted keys, I have to decrypt it first and then send it to `requests`. The problem is that `requests` only accepts file paths for specifying client keys/certificates. How can I make it accept a string?

Example of what I want to do:

```py
#X509
CLIENT_CERT_PATH = "path/to/cert" #perhaps I should convert this into a string too?

#PKey
CLIENT_PKEY_STRING = decrypt("path/to/encrypted_key")

response = requests.get(url = url, cert = (CLIENT_CERT_PATH, CLIENT_PKEY_STRING)) #how?
```

### Attempts

Tried [Python requests CA certificates as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410508/python-requests-ca-certificates-as-a-string/63353645#63353645) but I got the following behaviour: `AttributeError: module 'urllib3.contrib' has no attribute 'pyopenssl'`.

Also tried [Example of including a certficate in a post request with python and http.client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171751/example-of-including-a-certficate-in-a-post-request-with-python-and-http-client/49696785#49696785) and even adapted it to look like:

```py
class openSSLContext(requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.SSLContext):
    def __init__(self, method):
        pk = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open(CL_PKEY_PATH, "rb").read())
        cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open(CL_CERT_PATH, "rb").read())
        

requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.SSLContext = openSSLContext
```

but I don't know where to go from here.

### Versions

```cpp
Python 3.9.2
pyOpenSSL == 20.0.1
requests == 2.25.1
urllib3 == 1.26.4
```

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: The bellow code doesn't work

If you want to modify the second example you gave the bellow should do it

```py
class openSSLContext(requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.SSLContext):
    def __init__(self, method):
        pk = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open("./key.pem", "rb").read())
        cert = crypto.load_certificate(
            crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open("./cert.pem", "rb").read()
        )
        self.certfile = cert
        self.keyfile = pk


requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.SSLContext = openSSLContext
```

Comment: How would I modify the second awnser (the one I tried to adapt)?

Comment: sadly didn't work :( edited the post with the errors

Comment: You forgot to pass the method argument in `__init__` and `super.__init__`

Comment: already fixed that. I get a different error now

Comment: This is a patch and terible code by try passing `OpenSSL.SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD` instead of `method` `in super().__init__`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'PatchedContext' object has no attribute 'set_ciphers'` now

Comment: shouldn't the new context extend `requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.SSLContext` somehow? trying this shows: `File "C:\Faculdade\SSIN\proj\src\client\services.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(method)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)`

Comment: You are completely right fixed the coded and tested it should work now

Comment: your solution doesn't crash now, but the requests still aren't being authorized. I think the statements `self.certfile = cert` and `self.keyfile = pk` aren't doing anything

Comment: Well sorry but at this point I have no idea, I hope someone else is able to help