# How can I provide certificate and privkey as in-memory data in a requests https call with mTLS?

Tags: python-requests, urllib3, pyopenssl, mtls

I need to call some APIs which are authenticated via mTLS; `requests` supports this natively, by providing certificate and private key as paths to the corresponding files.

Now, in my setting, I will be retrieving certificate and private key at runtime and I would like to avoid storing them in temporary files on disk just to pass them over to `requests`, as it would worsen the security of the system.

I managed to perform such calls successfully by implementing what was suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71827847/10775275), but it turns out that importing from `urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl` is now [deprecated](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2680) by urllib3 and will be removed soon. In fact, this was pointed out in the comments and the suggested solution was to use `OpenSSL.SSL.Context` instead. However, when I try this I get a `AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'`.
I also tried to extend `Context` by copying over the definition of `PyOpenSSLContext.wrap_socket`, but this in turn requires to import from `urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl`.

I am aware of [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49696785), but I've not been able to make them work, and I'd prefer to avoid mockeypatching production code if at all possible.

Any help or suggestion is very well appreciated.